# Permission error launching Node.js container in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, circleci

I'm new to using AWS and containers and I'm running into an issue trying to launch a dockerized Node app on ElasticBeanstalk. I can run this container locally on multiple local machines with no issues. I'm really not sure where I should be looking to fix this.

Here's the error from AWS:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/\": permission denied": unknown.

In troubleshooting, I tried to push it through CircleCI and ran into this:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/node/app’: Permission denied
>   Exited with code 1

Is there a permission flag I need to set somewhere that I'm missing?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.15.0-jessie
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  app_node_modules:
services:
  app:
    build: .
    user: "node"
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
      - app_node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting up your EB environment?

Comment: I walked through the environment creation and set it up as a Web Server Environment, with Docker as the platform. I then upload a zipped version of my app with the node_modules folder removed to avoid any possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

`RUN chown -R root:root /home/node/app/node_modules/`

Add this to your DOCKER file